# C++ convert binary to decimal, octal

Tags: c++, function

Please i need help debugging the code below.
I am suppose to produce a code using functions that converts binary numbers to decimal or octal.
I keep getting error at the switch statement "error too few argument in function call".

```
#include <iostream.> 

long int menu();
long int toDeci(long int);
long int toOct(long int);

using namespace std;

int main () 
{
int convert=menu();

switch (convert)
{
case(0):
    toDeci();
    break;
case(1):
    toOct();
    break;
    }
return 0;
}
long int menu()
{
int convert;
cout<<"Enter your choice of conversion: "<<endl;
cout<<"0-Binary to Decimal"<<endl;
cout<<"1-Binary to Octal"<<endl;
cin>>convert;
return convert;
}

long int toDeci(long int)
{

long bin, dec=0, rem, num, base =1;

cout<<"Enter the binary number (0s and 1s): ";
cin>> num;
bin = num;

while (num > 0)
{
rem = num % 10;
dec = dec + rem * base;
base = base * 2;
num = num / 10;
}
cout<<"The decimal equivalent of "<< bin<<" = "<<dec<<endl;

return dec;
}

long int toOct(long int)
{
long int binnum, rem, quot;
int octnum[100], i=1, j;
cout<<"Enter the binary number: ";
cin>>binnum;

while(quot!=0)
{
    octnum[i++]=quot%8;
    quot=quot/8;
}

cout<<"Equivalent octal value of "<<binnum<<" :"<<endl;
    for(j=i-1; j>0; j--)
    {
        cout<<octnum[j];
    }

}
```

Comment: Except it won't compile so a debugger is pointless. toDeci() and toOct() take a long int parameter and you are not passing them anything

Comment: Ho many arguments do you pass to toDeci under case(0)? How many does it require?

Comment: Something like `long int toOct(long int)` is completely nonsensical, numbers are numbers, textual representations are textual representations.

Comment: You should use a string to read the radix 2 number.

Comment: Here's some useful info regarding _conversion_: [std::dec, std::hex, std::oct](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex). _bin_ is covered by [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) probably. Again: Numbers are numbers, how to represent these is a different thing.

Answer (score 3):

> I am suppose to produce a code using functions that converts binary numbers to decimal or octal.

There's no such thing like converting *binary numbers to decimal or octal* based on numerical representations as

```
long int toDeci(long int);
long int toOct(long int);
```

Such functions are completely nonsensical for any semantical interpretation.

Numbers are numbers, and their textual representation can be in *decimal*, *hex*, *octal* or binary format:

```
dec 42
hex 0x2A
oct 052
bin 101010
```

are all still the same number in a `long int` data type.

---

Using the c++ standard [I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) enable you to make conversions of these formats from their textual representations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand what you're trying to do. Here's an example that might help you ([demo](https://ideone.com/ekwdnd)):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  // 64 bits, at most, plus null terminator
  const int max_size = 64 + 1;
  char b[max_size];

  //
  cin.getline( b, max_size );

  // radix 2 string to int64_t
  uint64_t i = 0;
  for ( const char* p = b; *p && *p == '0' || *p == '1'; ++p )
  {
    i <<= 1; 
    i += *p - '0';
  }

  // display
  cout << "decimal: " << i << endl;
  cout << hex << "hexa: " << i << endl;
  cout << oct << "octa: " << i << endl;

  return 0;
}
```